# In Ruby, how can I define a string with interpolated variables before those variables are defined?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how can I define a string with interpolated variables before those variables are defined?

What do I need to do to perform the interpolation once those variables have values assigned?

```
tips = 'Hi,#{name},your order total price is #{price*count}'
name = 'roy'
price = 13.5
count = 10
tips.xxx = 'Hi,roy,your order total price is 135'
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are "varieties"? What is a "substitution string"? What does it mean that "varieties defind is behind substitution string"? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Answer (score 2):

For your case you can use `late interpolation`:

```
tips = 'Hi, %{name},your order total price is %{price}'
name = 'roy'
price = 13.5
count = 10
tips % {name: name, price: price * count}
# => "Hi,roy,your order total price is 135"
```

Link to documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-25

Answer (score 1):

In order to evaluate all between `#{...}` as Ruby code you must use double quotes, otherwise it'd just be printed as a commong String. And I guess you want to return something like `'Hi,roy,your order total price is 135'`, so, you need to create the name, price and count variables before, because if you don't do it then you'll get an `undefined local variable or method 'variable' for main:Object` error, so you could try:

```
name  = 'roy'
price = 13.5
count = 10
tips  = "Hi,#{name},your order total price is #{price*count}"
puts tips
# Hi,roy,your order total price is 135.0
```